# Error message when using COUNT(*)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, count

I'm currently receiving this error message:

> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
>   converted to string in ".

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a table. I know you can also use `mysqli_num_rows` but I thought I could just use `SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM table` but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I get the `Count(*)` to work?

My code:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category";

$select_all_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo "<div class='huge'> $select_all_categories </div>"
```

Comment: this has **NOTHING** to do with count. you need to RTFM http://php.net/mysqli_query. the function returns a statement HANDLE. you need to fetch a row of results from that handle and extract your count from the row.

Comment: If you'd read the docs: you would've seen that on success `mysqli_query` will return an object (in your case) and on failure it returns `false`.

Comment: `$select_all_categories` is an instance of `mysqli_result`, not a string. That class provides methods for accessing the data returned from the query, for example: `echo $select_all_categories->fetch_assoc()['COUNT(*)'];`

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because `mysqli_query` returns an object filled with data, data that needs to be fetched by either `mysqli_fetch_array` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

If you desire to get the count, you would need to do this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM category";
$select_all_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_categories);
echo "<div class='huge'> " . $data['count']. " </div>"
```

Comment: `$data['count']` or `mysqli_fetch_object()`

Comment: Thanks steve, I forgot that

Answer (score 1):

`$select_all_categories` is an *object*, it is not a simple string. Therefor, you cannot use `echo` with it.

You will need to get the actual results before you can even get to the point of being a viable string.

**In your case, for a simple count:**

```
  $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM category";

  $select_all_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

  $rows = $select_all_categories->fetch_assoc();

  $string = $rows[0]['count'];

  echo "<div class='huge'> $string </div>"
```

Notice that I gave the column the alias of `count` in the MySQL Query.

Your query (including `COUNT(*)`) is fine, it is not generating the error here. The error you're getting is a **PHP Error** - the script itself has issues. PHP is telling you that you can't echo an object. You can only echo strings, though PHP will convert most data types to strings for you (like integers for example) if you try to echo them.

Answer (score 1):

`$select_all_categories` variable it's a object, you can read about it in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). You can use with that methods `fetch_all`, `fetch_assoc`, `fetch_row`, etc.

In your case I recommend use `fetch_row`, example:

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'www', 'ccc');

$select_all_categories = $connection->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `category`');

var_dump($select_all_categories->fetch_row()); // fetch_row() will return "1" for my database
```